# Add additional space above plots using grid.arrange for title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `grid.arrange` to plot two charts on top of one another and would like to add a title above both charts using the `draw_label` function. However, as you will see in the example below, the label currently sits on top of the first plot. Is there any way to add extra space above the first plot for me to place the title?

[image]

```
## load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

## define simple theme
theme_background <- theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#232b2b", color = NA),
                          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#232b2b", color = NA))

## render plots
p1 <- mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = hp, y = wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_background

p2 <- mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_background

## create grid object
pGrid <- grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 1)

## add label to plots
ggdraw(pGrid) +
  draw_label(label = "This is a custom label that applies to both plots", 
             x = 0.01, y = 0.95, hjust = 0, vjust = 0, size = 10, lineheight = 1, color = "white")
```

Comment: Is `ggdraw` a function of `cowplot`? You could perhaps add the package for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `cowplot` package:

```r
# 1. Use Cowplot to arrange the plots
library(cowplot)
plot_row <- plot_grid(p1, p2, ncol = 1) +
              # To remove the border between title and plots
              panel_border(color = "#232b2b")

# 2. Create the title
title <- ggdraw() + 
  draw_label(
    label    = "This is a custom label that applies to both plots",
    fontface = 'bold',
    color    = 'white',
    x        = 0,
    hjust    = 0
  ) +
  theme(
    # add margin on the left of the drawing canvas,
    # so title is aligned with left edge of first plot
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#232b2b", color = NA),
    plot.margin     = margin(0, 0, 0, 7)
  )

# 3. Stack everything together
plot_grid(
  title, plot_row,
  ncol        = 1,
  # rel_heights values control vertical title margins
  rel_heights = c(0.1, 1)
) +
# To remove the border between the plots
theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#232b2b", color = NA))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @jwarz! One question - do you know if there is anyway to get rid of the thin white line between the title and the plots?

Comment: See my edit: Add `+ panel_border(color = "#232b2b")` to `plot_row`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Last question - that solution removed the line between the title and the first plot, but now there is a line between the first plot and the second plot. Any idea why that's happening/if there is a fix for that? My goal is to have everything sit atop that light gray background w/ no lines between the title and plots, or between plots

Comment: Nevermind - saw that if I added + theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#232b2b", color = NA)) to the last plot_grid object, that eliminates the line between plots. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1):

You could directly use the `top` argument in `grid.arrange`, although it will change the background and it does not allow for much control of the position (to the best of my knowledge, any further feedback on this would be appreciated):

```
pGrid <- grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 1, 
                  top = textGrob("This is a custom label that applies to both plots",
                                 gp=gpar(fontsize=15,font=8)))
```

[image]